# ¿Por que al contar el largo de una cadena se muestra una cantidad distinta a la de los elementos poseidos?

Tags: javascript

Teniendo esta cadena de texto y aplicandole la propiedad `length`

```js
var texto = "Hola soy una arroba \u0040 , un placer";
console.log(texto.length);
```

Devuelve: 33.

Si contamos nosotros mismos daria: 38.

> ¿Por qué da un cantidad distinta?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Da la cantidad correcta, el string es equivalente a

`"Hola soy una arroba @ , un placer"`

Cuando escribimos un string literal en un codigo fuente de Javascript (y en C, en Java y muchos otros lenguajes) el caracter `\` no se interpreta literalmente sino como parte de una "[secuencia de escape](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes)". En este caso, `\u` indica que lo que viene es un numero de caracter Unicode. Y en este caso  `\u0040` significa "caracter que ocupa el lugar `0040` (en hexa) en Unicode, el cual [corresponde](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0040/index.htm) al `@`.

Así que ese string que en tu *código fuente* ocupa 38 caracteres, en "realidad" (en ejecución -y en lenguajes compilados en el objeto binario compilado) ocupa 33.

Una secuencia de escape muy usada es el salto de línea. Cuando escribes

```js
var s = "Hola\nChau";
alert(s);
alert("largo: " + s.length);
```

a pesar que en el codigo fuente vemos (y tenemos) un caracter `\` y una `n` , en "realidad" esos caracteres no forman parte del string, sino que representan el caracter "salto de linea" (equivalente a `\u000A` ). Por eso, la longitud de ese string es 9, no 10.

Más detalles [aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/2yfce773(v=vs.94).aspx).